# ssh tunneling only working through PuTTY but not ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh-tunnel, rstudio-server

I have an AWS EC2 instance which is running `Rstudio` and `Shiny Server` on an `ubuntu` instance.
I have a Windows machine and have up until recently used PuTTY to connect to my instance (using ssh). Using `PuTTY` I also use ssh tunneling to localhost:8787. I can do this through the GUI or `PLINK`, both work fine ie.

`> plink -i myprivatekey.ppk -L 8787:localhost:8787 ubuntu@IPaddressAWS`

Or by using the GUI and going to `Auth -> tunneling` and setting it up that way.

Then I am able to open my browser and go to localhost:8787 and I get an Rstudio login.

**The Problem**

Now recently I started using `multipass` to connect to AWS via ubuntu to remove the middle man (PuTTY (Yes add a middle man to remove a middle man)). However I cannot get the tunneling to work.

`$ ssh -i myprivatekey.pem -L 8787:localhost:8787 ubuntu@IPaddressAWS`

But when I go to `localhost:8787` there is nothing there. I thought that what I did using `PuTTY` was the same as that. I have tried some variations that I have found online such as

`ssh -N -L SOURCE-PORT:127.0.0.1:DESTINATION-PORT -i KEYFILE ubuntu@IPAdressAWS`

When I add the verbose option `-v`, the logs seem okay;

```
Authenticated to MY INSTANCE ON AWS
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8787 forwarded to remote address localhost:8787
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8787.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8787.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

I could well be missing something very obvious (not great with linux). My main query is that: Isn't what I did using `PuTTY` the same as what I have tried using `ubuntu`?

Comment: -L option with source port:target host not localhost:target port, this is what I remember.